# Как отобрать роль у пользователя в Discord.py?

Tags: python, бот, discord.py, discord

Подскажите пожалуйста синтаксически простой способ для отбирания роли в Discord.py у пользователя. У меня есть способ выдачи роли, подскажите пожалуйста аналог для ее забирания:

```py
@bot.command()
async def color(ctx):
    role = ctx.guild.get_role(ID роли)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: [`remove_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=remove_roles#discord.Member.remove_roles)

Comment: У меня ошибку выдает. В remove_roles надо подавать тот же объект role?

Comment: Да, тот же объект. Я вам ссылку на документацию дал, там написано, какие исключения может выкидывать метод, посмотрите что за exception в вашем случае выходит